# Painted area white marks on the edges

Tags: painting, repainting, tape

A couple of days ago I decided to repaint some parts of the wall to get rid of the sweaty hand marks, coffee spills etc. I had newly painted the house so I have plenty of the exact same paint remaining. Applied it with a roller to the problem areas and  was hoping to get seamless paint job but what I got is this

[image: Paint with white marks around edges]

and this

[image: yet another failf paint job]

I have absolutely no idea as to why this might happen. I'm using a brand new roller and I'd stirred the can before applying the paint. Anyway, if there was something wrong with the paint then the inner region of the area wouldn't be normal either, would it?

I'm thinking of trying it with a masking tape but I'm hesitating because there's a chance of peeling the paint off when removing it. Any ideas?

Comment: How long had the paint sat in the bucket?   Is this latex paint?   How much paint was stored in the bucket?

Comment: https://simplydesigning.porch.com/how-to-touch-up-paint/.

Comment: It'd been sitting for about 40-45 days. It's acrylic paint. Both colors were in 10 liter buckets. Only 1/20 of the green one and about 2/5 of the pinkish one was remaining